# App Transport Security: configuring info.plist throws an error in React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm trying to fetch data with an unsecured http connection. I've configured info.plist file to bypass App Transport Security but when I build the app I get this error message:

[image]

Here is my info.plist file:

[image]

EDIT : I had to remove the build folder and build again. Then it worked.

Comment: There themes to be a syntax error in "done.js" at line 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, usually after you modify a project in XCode, you should do Product-> Clean.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding exceptions for Transport Security maybe try this to see if it will help. Allow Arbitrary Loads:

[image]